# intellisense is showing suggested words are compressed together, no space between them

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3NgU.png)This is what is showing when I type a word

I tried checking vs code setting but I found nothing that is helping.

If there is a way I can get to understand why is suggesting words that are compressed together.

I have tried other options but none is giving me answers

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: no, reviewers, this question does not need code. it is a UI problem (potentially a bug), and the screenshot is appropriate, though some further verbal description might be of some benefit.